# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Firebase Storage Swift SDK

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage, visionos

I'm encountering a fatal error in my Swift app at line 49 of FirebaseStorage/Storage.swift, where a Firebase Storage instance is being created using FirebaseApp.app()!. The error states "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."

Here's the relevant code snippet from FirebaseStorage/Storage:

```
@objc(storage) open class func storage() -> Storage {
    return storage(app: FirebaseApp.app()!)
}
```

App Delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil
    )
    -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

@main
struct MainApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
```

I'm using the environment variable to open the project:

```
open --env FIREBASE_SOURCE_FIRESTORE path/to/.xcodeproj
```

The issue seems to be related to forcibly unwrapping FirebaseApp.app(), and it's resulting in a nil value. I'm running the app on a XcodeBeta 15.1 beta 3 using VisionOS Beta Simulator.

Any insights on why FirebaseApp.app() might be nil and how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but none have been successful:

Cleaned the derived data.
Restarted Xcode.
Checked the Firebase configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're using `FirebaseApp.app()` before `FirebaseApp.configure()` gets called somehow. According to the document:

> This method should be called after the app is launched and before using Firebase services. This method should be called from the main thread and contains synchronous file I/O (reading GoogleService-Info.plist from disk).

I think you should re-check when get the `FirebaseApp.app` and also call `configure`.

```swift
@objc(storage) open class func storage() -> Storage? {
    if let defaultApp = FirebaseApp.app() {
        return storage(app: defaultApp)
    } else {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return storage(app: FirebaseApp.app())
    }
}
```